Analyzing \$g_m\$ vs \$V_{in}\$ for a common source config

I had this doubt while going through the book "Design of Analog CMOS Integrated Circuits" by B. Razavi, if we are to plot \$g_m\$ vs \$V_{in}\$ for the above circuit, then we have \$g_m\$ =0 till \$V_{in}\$ crosses the threshold voltage(\$V_t\$). Now, the MOSFET enters the Saturation region directly, and we have \$g_m=k(V_{in}-V_{t})\$ that gives \$g_m\$ to be directly proportional to \$V_{in}\$. My main problem arises is when the MOSFET leaves the saturation region and enters the triode region. We'll have \$g_m=k(V_{ds})\$ which has no term of \$V_{in}\$ in it. How do I go on analysing the circuit in the triode region? What will the final relation on graph look like?
The book provides  as the solution, I didn't quite get the solution provided in the book (on page 49). Any insights would help.

Are you able to write the equation that will plot the Id vs vin? And to get gm vs vin all you need to do is to take a derivative of Id = f(Vin).

@G36 yeah, I wrote down Id as a function of Vin, and took the derivative of it to get gm, but if I analyse that in the triode region, Id comes out to be a linear function of Vin, which on differentiation gives a constant value rather than a decreasing value as given in the actual graph. am I wrong here?

You can check this https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/333139/what-will-be-the-graph-of-g-m-vs-small-v-gs

@Varun yep i saw that but that question revolves around the linear operation of Mosfet only, not the bigger picture.

To find \$g_m\$ you need to take derivative of \$I_D = f(V_{IN}) \$
In saturation when \$V_{IN} > V_T\$, we have the following:
$$g_m = K_P(V_{IN} - V_T)$$
Assuming that \$I_D = \frac{K_P}{2}(V_{IN} - V_T)^2\$
The MOS will enter the triode region when  \$V_{DS} < V_{GS} - V_{T}\$:
The drain current in the triode region is equal to:
$$I_D =  K_P\: \left( V_{GS} - V_T - \frac{V_{DS}}{2} \right)V_{DS} = K_P\: \left( V_{IN} - V_T - \frac{V_{DD} - I_D R_D}{2} \right)(V_{DD}-I_D R_D) $$
And the \$g_m  = \frac{dI_D}{dV_{IN}}\$ in triode region is equal to:
$$g_m = \frac{1 - \sqrt{1 + K_P R_D ((2 + K_P R_D (V_{IN} - V_T) - 2 V_{DD} ) (V_{IN} - V_T))}  + K_P R_D (V_{IN} - V_T)}{R_D \sqrt{1 + K_P R_D ((2 + K_P R_D (V_{IN} - V_T) - 2 V_{DD} ) (V_{IN} - V_T))}} $$
And if I plot in LTspice assuming:
\$V_{DD} = 10V , R_D = 1k\Omega, K_P = 0.001, V_T = 1V\$
I get this:

If we plot \$g_m\$ in the triode region for \$V_{IN}\geqslant \frac{\sqrt{1 + 2V_{DD} R_D K_P} \:\: - \: 1}{K_P R_D} + V_T = 4.58258V\$ (for this Vin MOS enters triode region). I get exactly the same plot as in the LTspice.

ah yes! thanks a lot, I mistakenly considered Id to be constant on the rhs, silly me.

You are writing equations very nicely.May I know the tool you are using

@Confused This is nothing more than a LaTeX syntax.
